# Javascript Array from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

To update a Javascript Array (**eventDates**) I want to get the content via Ajax/PHP – sadly I don’t get it to work. Anyone knows how the PHP output (**data**) hast to look, that I can work with it?

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_ajax_registration.php?type=getDate&project="+val,
        data: "data",
        success: function(data){
            var eventDates = data;
        }
      });

      /*
      var eventDates = [{date: new Date(2014, 1-1, 28)}},
                {date: new Date(2014, 1-1, 18)},
                {date: new Date(2014, 6-1, 18)},];
      */


      function showEventDates(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getTime() == eventDates[i].date.getTime()) {
                return [true, ''];
            }
        }
        return [false, ''];
      }

      $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");       
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({       
        beforeShowDay: showEventDates

      }); 
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `echo json_encode($someArray)` from `_ajax_registration.php`.

Also, you won't be able to access `eventDates` outside of your ajax callback. You'll need to do:

```
function showEventDates(date) {
  for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; i++) {
    if (date.getTime() == eventDates[i].date.getTime()) {
      return [true, ''];
    }
  }
  return [false, ''];
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "_ajax_registration.php?type=getDate&project="+val,
  success: function(data){
    var eventDates = data;
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");       
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({       
      beforeShowDay: showEventDates
    }); 
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your fast and good awnser, sadly I have no idea how $someArray should look like to get it work ;(

Comment: If you comment out your static `eventDates` do you get the expected result?

Comment: That works fine. I just added an alert to see the result, with the comment code i get "[object Object],[object Object]" and with the value from data "["date: 1387926000","date: 1387926000"]" - my PHP is like this: 
$myArray[] = 'date: '.strtotime('25-12-2013');   
echo json_encode($myArray);

Comment: You would need to do like `$myArray[] = array('date' => strtotime('25-12-2013'));`

Comment: You don't want to try to build a json looking string, you want to use native data types.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but i just dont get it to work :( Im pretty sure, that i have done some stupid error somewhere, do you notice anything? https://pad.riseup.net/p/654654fgh345243fg

Answer (score 1):

You have an excrescent bracket after the first and an redundant comma on the last object. Try this:

```
 var eventDates = [{date: new Date(2014, 1-1, 28)},
            {date: new Date(2014, 1-1, 18)},
            {date: new Date(2014, 6-1, 18)}];
```

Comment: Also need to get rid of that last `,` for IE to work.

Comment: Sorry Peter, I was in the wrong row when answering. Your name and correction are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to to is, on the php side, take your array and

```
echo json_encode($myArray));
```

then, in the jquery you canjust:

```
$.GetJson('ajax_reg.php', { type : 'getDate', project': val }, function(data) {
    eventDates = date;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your fast awnser, sadly I have no idea how $myArray should look like ;( $myArray[] = strtotime('18-01-2014')*1000; doenst work